# What is a function selector?

Tags: abi, calldata, function-selector

I am reading an article, it says:

> To enable deployment on the Ethereum platform, the contract functions
>   are compiled into EVM bytecode and a piece of code called function
>   selector is added, which serves as an entry point into the contract
>   code.

Can some body please tell me what is a function selector?

I tried google and found:

> The first four bytes of the call data for a function call specifies
>   the function to be called. It is the first (left, high-order in
>   big-endian) four bytes of the Keccak-256 (SHA-3) hash of the signature
>   of the function. The signature is defined as the canonical expression
>   of the basic prototype without data location specifier, i.e. the
>   function name with the parenthesised list of parameter types.
>   Parameter types are split by a single comma - no spaces are used.

I can't understand what is call data?

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: `I can't understand what is call data?` - there is no mentioning of "call data" in the description that you've pasted here!

Comment: "The first four bytes of the 'call data' for a function call specifies the function to be called.", second quotation talks about call data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A function selector allows you to perform dynamic invocation of a function, based on the name of the function and the type of each one of the input arguments.

For example, suppose you have:

```
contract Contract1 {
    function func(uint256 x, uint8 y) public returns (uint32, uint32) {...}
}

contract Contract2 {
    Contract1 public contract1 = new Contract1();
    function func() public returns (uint32, uint32) {...}
}
```

Then you can call `Contract1.func` from `Contract2.func` as follows:

```
function func() public returns (uint32, uint32) {
    uint32[2] memory ret;

    address dest = address(contract1);

    bytes4 selector = contract1.func.selector;
    // Or bytes4 selector = bytes4(uint256(keccak256("func(uint256,uint8)") >> 224));

    bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, uint256(789), uint8(123));

    assembly {
        let success := call(
            gas,           // pass the remaining gas to the function
            dest,          // the address of the contract1 instance
            0,             // pass 0 wei to the function
            add(data, 32), // the actual data starts after the length of 'data'
            mload(data),   // the length of 'data' appears at the first 32 bytes
            ret,           // the address of the output
            8              // the size of the output
        )
        if iszero(success) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }

    return (ret[0], ret[1]);
}
```

If the invoked function is constant (either `pure` or `view`), then you can also use `staticcall`.

The example above is in assembly, but you can also use `call` directly in solidity.

I think that `staticcall` should be available starting from solidity v0.5.0.

Comment: "To enable deployment on the Ethereum platform, the contract functions are compiled into EVM bytecode and a piece of code called function selector is added, ", I thought we would add function selector in the contract which we are deploying.

Comment: Which part of 'call' deals with passing of two arguments: one of size uint256 and the other of size uint8?

Comment: @zak100: They are encoded in `data` and passed to `call` in `add(data, 32)`, which is an offset of 32 bytes from the address of `data`.

Comment: Contract1.func is returning two values but we are using a single argument 'success' to store the values in the assembly code? Is this not an error?

Comment: @zak100: No. `success` stores the return-value of `call`, which is either `0` or `1`. The return-value of the dynamically-invoked function will be stored at the address `ret`, and its size will be `8` bytes (see the last two parameters passed to `call`).

Comment: Why you say its dynamically invoked, we are passing the signature of function to selector and arguments of the function to encode, so how its dynamically invoked?

Comment: @zak100: In the coding example that I gave you, change `function func()` to `function func(bytes4 selector)`. Do you understand now why I call this "dynamic invocation"? You can pass any selector to `func`, and it will execute different functions in the assembly code. The function to be executed is determined at runtime rather than at compilation time - when `func` is compiled, the compiler has no knowledge of which function it will invoke. Hence the term "dynamic invocation".

Answer (score 2):

A function selector is the first four bytes of the calldata that specifies which function to call during a function call. For example, `contract.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address,uint256)", 0xtheAddressArgument, number/amount))`
During execution, the first 4 bytes from the `abi.encodeWithSignature(....)` in the above example represents the funtion's selector.