# Converting from Assembly to Solidity

Tags: assembly

I am trying to convert the assembly code into Solidity given at the link:
[What is a function Selector](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72363/what-is-a-function-selector)
The code is trying to invoke the function func(...) of  Contract1 given below:

```
contract Contract1 {
    function func(uint256 x, uint8 y) public returns (uint32, uint32) {...}
}
contract Contract2{
/* .......
 */
        assembly
        {
                let success := call(
                    gas,           // pass the remaining gas to the function
                    dest,          // the address of the contract1 instance
                    0,             // pass 0 wei to the function
                    add(data, 32), // the actual data starts after the length of 'data'
                    mload(data),   // the length of 'data' appears at the first 32 bytes
                    ret,           // the address of the output
                    8              // the size of the output
                )
                if iszero(success) {
                    revert(0, 0)
                }
        }
/*....*/
}
```

Is the following statement correct?

```
(success, errCode, arg1, arg2) =dest.func.value()(  uint256(789), uint8(123));
```

arg1 & arg2 would hold the two values returned by func() of Contract1. Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the following:

```
(bool success, ) = dest.call(data);
```

As the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#members-of-addresses) says:

> In order to interface with contracts that do not adhere to the ABI, or
>   to get more direct control over the encoding, the functions `call`,
>   `delegatecall` and `staticcall` are provided. They all take a single
>   `bytes memory` parameter and return the success condition (as a `bool`)
>   and the returned data (`bytes memory`). The functions `abi.encode`,
>   `abi.encodePacked`, `abi.encodeWithSelector` and
>   `abi.encodeWithSignature` can be used to encode structured data.

Suppose the next implementation of the `func()` of `Contract1`.

```
function func(uint256 x, uint8 y) public returns (uint32, uint32) {
    return(uint32(x), uint32(y));
}
```

Code of `Contract2`.

```
contract Contract2 {

    Contract1 public contract1 = new Contract1();

    function func() public returns (uint32, uint32) {

        uint32[2] memory ret;

        address dest = address(contract1);

        bytes4 selector = contract1.func.selector;
        //bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256("func(uint256,uint8)"));

        bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, uint256(789), uint8(123));
        (bool success, ) = dest.call(data);
        require(success);

        assembly {
            let size := returndatasize
            returndatacopy(ret, 0, size)
        }
        return (ret[0], ret[1]);
    }
}
```

Assembly used here is to manage the returned data of the function `call`. If you use the tuple `(bool success, bytes memory returnData)` you will get the returned data as `bytes memory` and you'll need to convert it to return as two `uint32` values.

Comment: call, send, transfer invoke the fallback function. Is it not possible to call the function by its name? Will this not create a confusion if we have a fallback function in Contract1?

Comment: @zak100 Yes, you can call `func()`by its name if you have the ABI or a contract instance of `Contract1`, but in the answer I suppose that you want to call the function using the selector without assembly code. It won't create any confusion because the `fallback` function is called if the contract doesn't recognise the selector or if no selector is provided.