# What is "selector" in ChainLink API call?

Tags: external-api, chainlink

I am using the example from chainlink to call an API; however, I am not sure it does.

```
function checkProof(string memory JobLocation, int job_id) public {
   Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(JOBID), address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

   req.add("get",JobLocation);

   req.add("path", "proof");

   sendChainlinkRequestTo(ORACLE_ADDRESS, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
}
```

I know it calls the following function

```
 function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bool _isProofCorrect, unit val) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId){
        customers[1].proof = _isProofCorrect;
 }
```

But, what does **selector** do in the above code (this.fulfill.selecor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does selector do in the above code (this.fulfill.selecor) ?

In your `buildChainlinkRequest` function, it [takes 3 arguments](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/20d36c7bdfac11b641206798b89c812aee12e859/evm-contracts/src/v0.7/ChainlinkClient.sol#L46):

- `bytes32 _specId`
- `address _callbackAddress`
- `bytes4 _callbackFunctionSignature`

The `bytes4 _callbackFunctionSignature` tells the Chainlink node what method to call when it returns the data. It is known as a [function selector](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72363/what-is-a-function-selector), and it allows the node to specify exactly what it needs to call back, in your case the `fulfill` function.

> Also, how can I pass an argument to the fulfill function? I am trying
> to update the proof variable of my customers map by using what
> chainlink calls.

Comment: As you suggested, I created another question. I would really appreciate if you can help with that  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90643/how-to-pass-argument-to-chainlink-selector

Comment: Great, I edited your question so it only reflected the singular question.