# How to pass argument to Chainlink selector?

Tags: oracles, chainlink

I have a mapping with integer keys and struct values.

```
mapping (int => Client) public customers;
```

Each customer has its own proof argument which I am trying to update with a Chainlink API call.
Here is my struct.

```
struct Client {
    int id,
    bool proof;
}
```

Here is how I request API get call

```
   function checkProof(string memory JobLocation, bytes32 JOBID) public {

      Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(JOBID, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

      req.add("get",JobLocation);

      req.add("path", "proof");

      sendChainlinkRequestTo(ORACLE_ADDRESS, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
}
```

And this function triggers the following function

```js
     function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bool _isProofCorrect, unit val) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId){
            customers[1].proof = _isProofCorrect;  
}
```

**How can I update the proof argument of my Construct by using customer ID. For example:**

```
customers[<customer_id>].proof = _isProofCorrect;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all [Chainlink API calls](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request), the `fulfil` method only takes 2 arguments.

- `bytes32 _requestId` The `requestId` of the Chainlink API call.
- `<type> _data` The `_data` that is being returned by the Chainlink API call.

This means you can't pass 3 parameters.

What this means, is that you can **map your `requestId` to your value**, and it'll look something like this.

```
mapping (bytes32 => uint) public requestMapping;

function checkProof(string memory JobLocation, bytes32 JOBID) public {

      Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(JOBID, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
      req.add("get", JobLocation);
      req.add("path", "proof");
      bytes32 requestId = sendChainlinkRequestTo(ORACLE_ADDRESS, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
      requestMapping[requestId] = customerId;
}

     function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bool _isProofCorrect, unit val) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId){
            uint256 value = requestMapping[_requestId]
            customers[value].proof = _isProofCorrect;  
}
```

Comment: Patrick, I asked another question regarding the Chainlink oracles. I would appreciate if you can give it a look if you get a chance.