# Json RPC eth_sendTransaction data parameter

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, oracles, clients, chaindata

I have a question concerning the data parameter of the json RPC method eth_sendTransaction.

Is it possible to send any kind of data structure with this method to a smart contract?

Is it possible to store the data send with this method on the blockchain then, by storing it in a variable within the smart contract code?

I am asking because when we can send any external data to the client, why the need of oracle's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the data parameter needs to get the function selector ([Example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/72364/68019)) and encoded arguments if needed when calling a method of a smart contract. It isn't used for like sending a custom string saying "Hi there" or so which then could be stored in a variable!

=> Have a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBzu4.png) under "Execute a Function on a Deployed Contract"

> [image: eth_sendTransaction() parameters]
>
> Parameters to call a function with eth_sendTransaction()

Comment: But can't I send the string as arguments encoded?