# How to get MethodID of a function in a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, web3.py, python, abi

If I look in the past transactions of a smart contract that called a function, I can see the MethodID being used.

[image]

If the function was never used in the past, I would never know what was the method ID. Is there any way I could generate this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function selector or method id is the first 4 bytes of the hash of the method name and the parameters. This is documentend here https://solidity-by-example.org/function-selector/

More details are also available here [What is a function selector?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72363/what-is-a-function-selector)
There are also database where you can look these up. For example https://www.4byte.directory/