# Cannot get correct MethodID from a function

Tags: solidity, transactions, uniswap, keccak, function-selector

I am trying to derive the MethodID from the function, based on [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118336/how-to-get-methodid-of-a-function-in-a-smart-contract).

However, when I look at this [transaction on Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcf7c10fea965a51dfe4c73735cbb22cddecd9a52b3f9472717434235be791d8b), I cannot see how `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMin, address[] path, address to, uint256 deadline)` can hash to `0x791ac947`.

Getting the first 4 bytes of `keccak256("swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint256, uint256, address[], address, uint256)")` gives `0x2e701daa`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must remove spaces in between them and wrap that into `bytes4` so that you can get the first 4 bytes.

```
function getHash() external pure returns(bytes4 example){
    example = bytes4(keccak256("swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)"));
}
```

well this returns the value you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Almost there!

You need to remove the spaces. So `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)` -> `0x791ac947`. Can be easily tested online at https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html